# build Compiler 'protobuf' from source and use it with it's shared objects from within cmake

Tags: jenkins, cmake, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers

I'm using a **CMake** build in a **Jenkins** environment and want to build the **protobuf** compiler from source.

This all works but in the next step I'm trying to use the compiler to translate my proto files which doesn't work, cause it cannot find it's own **shared objects**. I've tried defining the search path in the `CMakeLists.txt` file but it won't detect the shared object location in my repository tree `$PRJ_MIDDLEWARE/protobuf/lib`. I've tried telling cmake or the system where to search by defining:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "$ENV{PRJ_MIDDLEWARE}/protobuf/lib")
set(ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} "$ENV{PRJ_MIDDLEWARE}/protobuf/lib:$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}")
```

But it always fails when trying to invoke the `protoc` compiler I just build. I tried invoking ´´ldconfig´´ from **CMake** but that doesn't work cause the **jenkins** user doesn't have the right to do this. Currently my only solution is to login to the build server an do this manually as `root`. But that is not how I want to do this... the next release moves to a new directory—this has to be done again. Do I have other options? Preferably directly from **CMake**, from **Jenkins** or maybe even **Protocol Buffers**?

Thank you

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind:

1. Build protobuf compiler as a static binary (I don't know if that's possible but it usually is.)
2. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before invoking cmake to point to the location of protoc shared libraries.